# Polymer: ¿Cómo puedo obtener los valores seleccionados de un paper-menu/listbox?

Tags: html, polymer

Me gustaría saber como puedo obtener una lista, un objeto o un array, etc. de un paper-menu o paper-listbox donde el usuario puede escoger más de un valor.

HTML:

```html
<paper-menu attr-for-selected="value" selected-value="{{selectionMuscles}}" multi>
   <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{muscles}}">
     <paper-item value="{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</paper-item>
   </template>
</paper-menu>
<div>[[selectionMuscles]]</div>
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque está en inglés. Si quieres continuar haciendo la pregunta en inglés ha de ser en el sitio http://stackoverflow.com. Puedes [editar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/32969/edit) tu pregunta para traducirla. Hecho eso retiraría el voto de cierre. Un saludo

Comment: Perdona! ahora mismo lo hago.

Comment: Sin problema. Te recomiendo que te pases por el [tour](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) o por [meta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/) para aprender más del funcionamiento de este sitio ^^

Answer (score 0):

Ambos (paper-menu y paper-listbox) tienen unas propiedades llamadas "selectedItems" y "selectedValues" que te devuelven un array cada una de los elementos seleccionados.

Te recomiendo ésta [página](https://elements.polymer-project.org/browse?package=paper-elements) oficial (en inglés) con documentación y ejemplos bastante útil.

y ésta [otra](http://vaadin.github.io/gwt-polymer-elements/demo/#gwt/JavaApiWidget) (en inglés) en la que explica menos elementos pero con ejemplo en "Java" si es que utilizas GWT.

Comment: Ya lo hago, pero no me devuelve los valores, ¿Cómo seria la correcta sintaxis de la obtención de estos valores? Porqué he probado de todo y estoy estancado.

Comment: Ya lo probé y si me devuelve valores. Claro, puse un id="menu" en el paper-menu para referenciarlo desde un botón `itms = document.getElementById("menu").selectedItems;`. Me devolvió objetos tipo paper-item. puse un for para ver la propiedad `innerText` de cada uno

Comment: Perfecto! ya me funcionó. Muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Un gusto ayudar. Sólo por formar un buen hábito, recuerda marcar la respuesta que te ayudó mejor a resolver tu problema.

Comment: Hecho! Si te pudieras pasar por mi otra pregunta me harías un gran favor: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33607/polymer-c%C3%B3mo-puedo-cargar-valores-din%C3%A1micos-en-un-paper-item-dentro-de-un-pape