# Polymer: ¿Cómo puedo cargar valores dinámicos en un paper-item dentro de un paper-menu?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

Me gustaría conseguir que desde código javascript, se cargara una lista de objetos que obtengo desde firebase, a la propiedad "items" de un paper-item dentro de un paper-menu. Aquí os dejo mi código:

HTML:

```html
<paper-menu class="menuList" id="disciList" attrForSelected="value" selectedItems="{{selectionDisci}}" multi>
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{disciplines}}">
     <paper-item value="{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</paper-item>
  </template>
</paper-menu>
```

Javascript:

```js
var disciplines = [];
      var i = 0;
      
      var disciRef = db.ref(exercises.node + exercises.discinames);
      disciRef.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
          var key = childSnapshot.key;
          disciplines["name" + i] = childSnapshot.key;
          i++;
        });
      });
```

Obtengo la lista correctamente, pero no encuentro la manera de cargar {{items.name}} más el valor de "i" (0-1-2-3...) en el paper-item. Si existe otra manera de cargar la lista dinámica, estoy abierto a aprender.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

En base a las maneras en que yo he logrado eso es mediante:

```
Polymer({

   ready: function() {
      this._disciplines = ['Disciplina inicial primaria', 'Disciplina inicial secundaria'];
    },

    _creaItem: function() {
      this.push('_disciplines', 'Disciplina ' + this._disciplines.length);
    }

  });
```

Escríbelo tal como se ve aquí en tu etiqueta script.

Te explico. El en primer objeto `ready` se asigna una función que se ejecuta cuando los elementos polymer estén listos. Por ejemplo, estoy asignando al arreglo `_disciplines` un arreglo con los datos iniciales.

La segunda es un objeto que llama a una función y lo puedes utilizar como tal.

```
<paper-button on-click="_creaItem">Agregar</paper-button>
```

Y como código ejemplo: agrega al arreglo objetos individualmente. En éste caso, se agrega otro objeto con texto "Disciplina" concatenándole la cantidad de objetos en el arreglo.

Utiliza el método que más te convenga (llenar tu arreglo al momento de carga o bajo demanda. Llena tu arreglo con otro arreglo o inserta objeto por objeto)

Comment: He puesto lo mismo que tenia pero cambiando la manera en que añado valores al array:  
  
this.push('_disciplines', key);  
  
Y me da el siguiente error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.push is not a function..   
  
¿He hecho algo mal?

Comment: Estoy viendo que lo que me falla es que no puedo acceder desde dentro del foreach de firebase a un array de fuera.. alguien tiene idea de como hacerlo?

Comment: Para que reconozca la función push debes hacer que _disciplines sea un arreglo. Para ésto podrías hacer `this._discliplines = [ ];` en la función de ready.

Comment: Por qué dices que no puedes acceder a un array de *fuera* ?

Comment: porqué cuando intento acceder al _disciplines, dentro del snapshot.forEach tiene unos valores y fuera está vacio

Comment: Intentaste utilizar `this.disciplines["name"+i] = ...` ? con ese disciplines dentro del foreach estás creando *otro* arreglo disciplines con vida limitada a ese foreach.

Comment: ah.. y cómo hago para guardar esos valores del foreach y sean los que se agreguen a los items del template?

Comment: Intenta con `this.disciplines[..."`  en lugar de sólo `disciplines` dentro del forEach

Comment: snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {  
          var key = childSnapshot.key;  
          console.log(key);  
          _disciplines.push(key);  
        });  
esto es lo que hago actualmente y con el THIS. no me funciona tampoco

Comment: para el push es `this.push('_disciplines', ....)`

Comment: sí sí, lo he probado así también y al estar dentro del forEach me dice que el push no es una function.. lo ponga como lo ponga el push.. ¿hay alguna manera de que hablemos y puedas mirar mi código más fluidamente? Si no es posible tranquilo, intentaré buscar alguna otra manera con polymerfire o algo